# Android: Can't find generated XML file

Tags: android, xml

I am working on a method that writes an XML file to the device. I've allowed external storage in the manifest file, but I can't find the file at the location it should be.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void write (){   
 Serializer serial = new Persister();
 File sdcardFile = new File("/Prueba/file.xml");
    Item respuestas = new Item();

   try {
 serial.write(respuestas, sdcardFile);
   } catch (Exception e) {
// There is the possibility of error for a number of reasons. Handle this     appropriately in your code
e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Log.i(TAG, "XML Written to File: " + sdcardFile.getAbsolutePath());
   }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sdcard File path problem. Here is an exaple that write string in file.xml file.

```
File myFile = new File("/sdcard/file.xml");



try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/file.xml");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append("encodedString");
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

You able to get External Storage name by this way,

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```